# how to align qtextedit

Tags: qt, qtextedit

Hi guys,QTextEdit Insert a picture and text in one line.How to make the text in the center of a line.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4v7h.png)

Comment: try to reduce the height of your image.

Comment: thanks,Is there any other way?I use QTextBrowser display text and picture

Comment: with a QLineEdit, that's won't be easy. maybe you can try to create a class inheriting to QLineEdit and overload the paint method. in that method you would be able to draw the text and move the image where you want it to be. But it's not so clean for what you wanna do and I think that it will be way easier for you to have smiley with the same height than your text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem,thanks

```
 QTextImageFormat imageFormat;
 imageFormat.setWidth(image.width());
 imageFormat.setHeight(image.height());
 //center the image
 imageFormat.setVerticalAlignment(QTextImageFormat::AlignMiddle);
 imageFormat.setName(file);
 cursor.insertImage(imageFormat);
 ui->textEdit_Send->setFocus(Qt::MouseFocusReason);
```